# Search closest next value in javascript array

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript array like `var test = [2,5,8,12,56];` and now I want to search the closest next value of 9. So the output is 12 in this case (and not 8!).

Comment: What should the output be if you search for 57?

Comment: How long is the array normally? Only a few elements like above or several thousands?

Comment: If the array is always sorted, you can simply do a binary search for the value in the sorted array with the slight modification that the upper bound should be returned when the search interval becomes empty. This gives O(log n) complexity whereas the naive approach gives O(n) complexity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well here's a simple way to do it:

```
function getNextVal(arr, val) {
    // omit the next line if the array is always sorted:
    arr = arr.slice(0).sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});

    for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i] >= val)
            return arr[i];

    // return default value when val > all values in array
}
```

You don't say what to return if the search value is in the array, so I've assumed you want to return it. If by "closest next value" you meant that it should always return the next number *higher* than the search value change `arr[i] >= val` to use `>` instead of `>=`.

If you have a large array you probably want some kind of binary sort instead of just going through from the beginning.

Comment: Be warned that `sort` is destructive.

Comment: @nnnnnn Naturally. Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: @some - That's OK, these details are easy to miss: I had to edit my answer to include a sort callback function (so that it would actually sort in _numeric_ order, which I didn't think of at first).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can try if the array is sorted, you need to tune for for boundry cases, this is just for idea of algorithm...

```
NUM is input
TEST is your array
INDEX is index variable

For INDEX from 0 .. TEST.SIZE -1 
    IF NUM > TEXT[INDEX]
        RETURN TEXT[INDEX]
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple code is given below. Hope this will help you

```
   var test = [2,5,8,12,56];
var key = 9;
var closestNext=1000;
for(var i=0;i<test.length;i++)
{
    if(test[i] > key)
    {
         if(test[i]<closestNext)
         {
             closestNext = test[i];
         }
    }

} 

alert(closestNext);
​
```

[see the working one here](http://jsfiddle.net/g8Zrm/)

Comment: yeah.. misread the question that he need the next one to 12.. http://jsfiddle.net/g8Zrm/

Answer (score 0):

1 Start by sorting the array, using `arr.sort();`, just sorts the values in the ascending order (`3,6,4,7,1 --> 1,3,4,6,7`), then just iterate:

```
function getNext(inputVal,arr)
{
    arr.sort();;
    for (var i=0;i<arr.lenght;i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] >= inputVal)
        {
            return arr[i];
        }
    }
    throw new Error('Out of range');
}
```

Comment: Note that `arr.sort()` will sort in dictionary order (e.g., "12" before "2") unless you supply a callback to do otherwise, and also you may want to make a copy of the array before sorting rather than changing the input array.

Answer (score 0):

If you *know* the array is always going to be sorted or if it is reasonable to sort the array beforehand (e.g. when the array doesn't change very often but you need a lot of retrievals), you can use a binary search on the sorted array.

If the value is not found in the array, the upper bound is returned which indicates the smallest element greater than the given value. This gives O(log n) complexity on average whereas the naive approach (looping over the whole array) gives O(n) complexity on average.

```
// Binary search
// Adapted from http://jsfromhell.com/array/search
function binarySearch(arr, val, insert) {
    var high = arr.length, low = -1, mid;
    while (high - low > 1) {
        mid = (high + low) >> 1;
        if (arr[mid] < val) low = mid;
        else high = mid;
    }
    if (arr[high] == val || insert) {
        return high;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

function getClosestNext(arr, val) {
    // Get index
    var i = binarySearch(arr, val, true);
    // Check boundaries
    return (i >= 0 && i < arr.length) ? arr[i] : null;
}
```